# Boot stalls, login screen never loads

Tags: 20.04, login

This is on a Thinkpad t480s with Intel graphics running 20.04. I upgraded from 18.04 over the summer and haven't had any issues until today. When booting, I get a log screen that shows

```
/dev/nvme0n1pd: clean, 5049190/31227904 files, 63916981/124895488 blocks
```

It just sits there indefinitely. I tried `fsck` with a live USB and there were no errors. I then tried removing `gdb3` and reinstalling. Now it loads to a different log screen, all with

```
[ OK ] <message here>
```

If I `ctrl-alt-f1`, I get a login screen, which I can then log in, but some things don't work right. For instance, the dock isn't showing, terminals won't load (either through ctrl-alt-t or through the activities search - doesn't even show up there), and some apps won't load (VS Code, for instance). It's like gdb3 is just poorly configured. Any suggestions on how to get back to normal? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F2. It will then ask you for your username. Type in your username. It will then ask you for your password. Type in your password. You are using a virtual terminal when you press Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Same thing happens with Ctrl+Alt+F2-6. Ctrl+Alt+F7 brings you back to the GUI.

Try running  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in the virtual terminal. Then select the option that you aren't using. After that, do `sudo shutdown now -r`. That will restart your PC. It should work now. If it still doesn't work, follow the steps in the 1st paragraph, then go to the 4th paragraph.

After you reboot and are in the virtual terminal again, type `sudo lightdm` or `sudo`  followed by the other option from the sudo dpkg-reconfigure command, then follow the step in the 2nd paragraph. The login screen should be there now.